# ExtendScript Illustrator (CS6 or newer) Stroke Profile

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Im using ExtendScript to create a bunch of paths in illustrator CS6.
How can I apply a stroke profile (or "stroke-width profile" or "variable stroke-width")?

thanks!